# How to run Angular build on limited resources and old computer

Tags: angular, ubuntu, ram

I am not an expert!

I am building Angular 9 web application on my work laptop.
Which is working fine!

However due to unavoidable reasons, I am not able to collect my work laptop for few days.
I have a old computer (AMD Athlon) with 1 GB RAM at home that runs
Ubuntu 18.04 (Actually Lubuntu).

I thought of building the Angular 9 code on my home computer.
For this I got code using git. I installed nodejs 10 and installed Angular 9 globally.

However when i fired the ng build command, it didnt complete even after 1.5 hours!
The computer stopped responding too for mouse or keyboard input. I had to restart it.
I had seen after few minutes of firing the build command, the RAM usage was almost 90-100% and CPU was also 100%. No wonder my computer was not responding.

I would like to know if its possible to build on limited resources an Angular 9 application.

I tried using --max-old-object-size by giving 512 as value(512 MB). It gave javascript heap issue.

Can someone help me running the build successfully on my home computer, please?

Thanks

Comment: Try to disable build optimizer and aot by running this command `ng b --prod --aot=false --build-optimizer=false`

Comment: I tried this suggestion. It still takes ages to build. Finally it gives error and stops(after probably 2 hrs)